# Compare strings with Array of Strings Mule 4

Tags: mule, string-comparison, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I have to compare/exactly match one String against an array of String.

**Input:**

```
{
"country": "India",
"countries": "India,Russia,USA"
}
```

**Output:**

If **country** matches from the List present in **countries** then Return True, if not then return False.

Answer (score 1):

It usually makes sense to separate your problem, in this case in two parts

1. Parse the list of countries as a list
2. Check whether your country is present or not

For 1 you can use something like [splitBy](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-core-functions-splitby). And then for 2 you can use [contains](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-core-functions-contains).

So, you can do something like:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

fun check(p) = do {
    var countries = splitBy(p.countries, ",")
    ---
    contains(countries, p.country)
}

---
check(payload)
```

Comment: Suppose "country : 'Ind' ", then it should match.. so will your code work in this case??

Answer (score 0):

### %dw 2.0
output application/json

payload.countries contains  payload.country

Comment: Answers should provide an explanation, not just code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**contains** could be used to check whether the substring (country) is present in available string (list of countries).

However, It would return `true` even if an incomplete substring like `"Ind"` is provided for country as technically the substring is present in the available countries string.

So, **splitBy** could be used to split the available string (countries) to individual substrings and checked with the country substring.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload.countries splitBy(",") contains payload.country
```